# How to query a matrix for multiple values and receive value

Tags: excel

I am a bit lost with Excel. I have two values

- Length
- Weigth

I am looking for a solution for the problem below:

Take `length` and `weight` from the input values, find the next **upper** value for both in the matrix and receive the `value` from the value column. And if there is no upper value for my input, I want to have a fallback and always use the value `1.0`.

How to solve this?

I have a matrix which has these values inside:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(SORT(FILTER(MATRIX, (LENGTHS>length)*(WEIGHTS>weight)),1,1),2,1),1,3),1)
```

, where MATRIX, LENGTHS, and WEIGHTS refer to the data on the right, whilst length and weight refer to the cells containing 80 and 450.

Just seen you said H6 was what I referred to as length - if so:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(SORT(FILTER(K6:M11, (K6:K11>H6)*(L6:L11>H7)),1,1),2,1),1,3),1)
```

in H8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMATCH` to get the next value as follow:

```
=LET(f, FILTER(D2:F7, D2:D7>B1), 
 IFNA(INDEX(INDEX(f,,3), XMATCH(B2, INDEX(f,,2),1)), 1))
```

[image: excel output]

If you want to treat the error when the length condition is not satisfied, you can modify it as follows:

```
=LET(f, FILTER(D2:F7, D2:D7>B1, ""), IF(@f="", "No match for length condition",
IFNA(INDEX(INDEX(f,,3),XMATCH(B2, INDEX(f,,2),1)), 1)))
```